# Protractor: creating an array from nested elements

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

I'm trying to get elements in my DOM and return them as an array.  They are nested.  I want protractor to return something like this:

```
{
 category_title: "cat1",
 items: {item_title: "item1"}, {item_title: "item2"}
},
{
 category_title: "cat2",
 items: {item_title: "item1"}, {item_title: "item2"}
}
```

DOM:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <div id="category-title">{{ category.title }} </div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in category.items">
        <div id="item-title">{{ item.title }} </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm trying in Protractor:

```
return element.all(by.repeater("category in categories")).map(function(elm) {
    var category_title = elm.element(by.id('category-title')).getText(),
    var t = {
              category_title: category_title,
              dimensions: {}
            };
    // After this part, I'm lost...
    return elm.all(by.repeater("item in category.items")).map(function(elm) {
        return {
                 category_title:  category_title,
                  dimension:  elm.element(by.id('item-title')).getText(),
               }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, but I'm not 100% sure it's correct

```
return element.all(by.repeater("category in categories")).map(function(elm) {
    return {
               category_title: elm.element(by.id('category-title')).getText(),
               items: elm.all(by.id("item-title")).getText()
           }
})
```

Comment: to get the initial input you specified, you would replace `items: elm.all(by.id("item-title")).getText()` with `items: elm.all(by.id("item-title")).map(function(elm2) {return {item_title: elm2.getText()}})` but your answer is accurate, with just a format mismatch